# How to access strings from Resource file in WPF XAML

Tags: wpf

How To Access Strings from Resource File in WPF specifically in XAML(not code Behind).
    I have 1 resource file suppose Resource1.resx. It has Name & value Pair. e.g.

Name1 ==> ABC 
Name2 ==> XYZ

Now I want to put these names into ComboBox in XAML..

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:
Define the xmlns for your Resources file

```
  xmlns:resx="NAMESPACE in which your resouces are"
```

Now you can access your resources assuming Resource1 you named your resources file

```
  <TextBlock Text="{x:Static resx:Resources1.Name1}"
```

Since you want to fill the combobox with all your resources values, i am afraid for that you will need to write the wrapper property in your ViewModel which will accumalate all the resource to which you can bind your Combobox ItemsSource property.

Or you will have to create number of comboboxitems to do it like

```
<ComboBox>
  <ComboBoxItem Content="{x:Static resx:Resources1.Name1}"/>
  <ComboBoxItem Content="{x:Static resx:Resources1.Name2}"/>
</ComboBox>
```